# Django - Authenticate returns None despite AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS

Tags: python, django

I try to make a login using a `LoginView` class. I just can't login. It always says  that my password is wrong but it isn't (I checked it with `check_password()`). I already set `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']` in my settings.py.

Here's my `clean` function in my custom `AuthenticationForm`:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    username = cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    print(user)
    print(username)
    print(password)

    try:
        us = User.objects.get(username=username)
        print(us)
        print(us.check_password(password)) # This returns True!!!
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass

    if user is not None:
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Dieser Account ist deaktiviert. Du kannst ihn über deine E-Mail aktivieren.")
    else:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Falsches Passwort")
    return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ModelBackend authenticate method does this:

```
 def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
    if username is None:
        username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
    try:
        user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
        # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
        UserModel().set_password(password)
    else:
        if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
            return user
```

and `user_can_authenticate` is:

```
  def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
        """
        Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
        that attribute are allowed.
        """
        is_active = getattr(user, 'is_active', None)
        return is_active or is_active is None
```

Does your user have is_active set to True?

Comment: That was my fault. I thought you would get the user no matter whether `is_active` is `False` or `False`.